# Update the column status based on a condition in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where I have `ID` & `Status`. I want the all the unique `ID`'s and status. Even if one of the status value is no. 
I want to update the status in the table as "No" for ID's that have either one of their status value as "No" and delete the rest of the rows.

The corresponding ID's status should be no. How can I achieve this

```
ID Status
---------
1  Yes
1  No
1  No
2  Yes
2  No
3  No
3  No
4  Yes
4  Yes
5  No
5  Yes
3  Yes
```

Expected output:

```
ID  Status
----------
1   No
2   No
3   No
4   Yes
5   No
```

Comment: Use MIN(Status)

Comment: `Select ID, min(Status) from tableName Group by ID`

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID, 
case when sum(case when Status = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Status
from table 
group by ID
```

Comment: select ID, 
case when sum(case when Status = 'No' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'No' else 'Yes' end as Status
from T2 
group by ID -- > gives the right output

Comment: @Legend,yes,you are right. If one is wrong then all is wrong. A little more concern, make sure you handle null value well if you got some missing data, typicallu you can treat it as no as well.